# Rewrite all requests from a single directory to a script - .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I need change files url in one folder in my server. It should prevent from direct download but  I don't need `deny from all` rule.

Example:
typical direct link:
http://www.domain.com/foder1/folder2/file.ext

and I need this:
http://www.domain.com/page.html?file=foder1/folder2/file.ext

so in my case I need add this string (`page.html?file=`) to url. Maybe I'm wrong But I think it must be redirect becouse rewrite not execute page.html just only change (view of) url.

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you need to use mode_rewrite.  It will execute the `page.html` file just fine.  It just won't update the URL in the browser bar.  So, the user will have no idea they have been directed from the actual file to a script/html page. (As they probably should not!)

Here is an example:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule !^foder1/folder2(/|$) page.html?file=%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```